# Express $10$ as a difference of consecutive primes in $15$ ways

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would you express $10$ as a difference of two consecutive primes in $15$ different ways?

I started by constructing the classic Diophantine equation in two variables: $(1)x + (-1)y = 10$

But, there are just too many constraints here to which the traditional method of solving Diophantine equations cannot be applied. How do I solve this?

Comment: Get hold of a list of primes (or generate one) and search for gaps equal to $10$

Comment: `let ps = sieveFrom 1; ds = zip (tail ps) ps in take 20 (filter ((== 10) . uncurry (-)) ds)
[(149,139),(191,181),(251,241),(293,283),(347,337),(419,409),(431,421),(557,547),(587,577),(641,631),(701,691),(719,709),(797,787),(821,811),(839,829),(929,919),(1031,1021),(1049,1039),(1061,1051),(1163,1153)]`

Comment: I can use a computer to do it, but is there a way to do it without electronic media?

Comment: This question is as exersice in burton's number theory book. Can someone tell me if the author is expecting the reader to use any electric device pc or calculator for generating these primes? Or he just want us to try and find primes ourself. But i think that's very tedious job. I am confuse. Kindly explain